# How to install 32bit Libraries in 64bit Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, gcc, libraries

I want to install Intel Parallel Studio XE, during installation I get the following error message:

> 32-bit libraries not found
>   32-bit libraries not found on this system.
>   This product release requires the presence of 32-bit compatibility libraries >when running on Intel(R) 64 architecture systems. One or more of these >libraries could not be found:
>   libstdc++ (including libstdc++6)
>   glibc
>   libgcc
>   Without these libraries, the compiler will not function properly. Please >refer to Release Notes for more information.

If I try to install lib32stdc++ I get the following message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
>   lib32stdc++6-4.9-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
>   Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
>   lib32stdc++6-5-dbg : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg but 4.7.4-3ubuntu12 is to be installed
>   Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg but 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 is >to be installed
>   Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.9-dbg but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2 is >to be installed
>   lib32stdc++6-5-dbg-s390x-cross : Conflicts: lib32stdc++6-4.9-dbg-s390x-cross but 4.9.3-13ubuntu2cross1 is to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Since I'm new to Linux can someone explain this error message and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want the debug package here. What you likely need to install are `libstdc++6:i386` `libgcc1:i386` and perhaps other 32-bit versions of libraries. Generally, you can append `:i386` to the normal package name, to install the 32-bit version, where appropriate, and when the package supports multi-arch.

Comment: Those two commands work fine, but why do i need to add the 6 and 1 respectively? Also this does not include the glibc library and it doesn't change my original error message from Intel Parallel Studio XE :(
Anymore ideas?

Comment: I don't know what all libraries it needs exactly. The 6 and 1 in the package names, are part of the package names. They are the library version numbers. If you want to read more, I'd suggest reading the Debian Packaging Manual. You presumably also need `libc6:i386` as well.